# Sitecore rich text editor dialog, page scrolls to top

Tags: sitecore

It appears that the default behavior for the rich text editor dialog in Page Editor is to scroll the entire page back to the top. This creates bad UX on long pages, since after you're done editing, you have to scroll back down the page and figure out where the text is that you edited.

Anyone know how to make the page stay scrolled to where it was?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is related, since I am not able to reproduce your problem, but it reminds me of a bug in the Sitecore client that showed up in Internet Explorer and Firefox versions, where the content tree pane would do the same (scroll up after interaction). Please take a look at  [this StackOverflow question for a possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418448/sitecore-content-tree-scroll-to-top-in-firefox).

Furthermore I want to give you the advice to build up pages in Sitecore using small building blocks (multiple hierarchical placeholders with small renderings). Only then you would be able to leverage the full potential of the system, regarding page editing features and personalization. Also, only then a content editor can alter the presentation in the Experience Editor (Page Editor for older versions). Putting long pages of HTML-code in a single rich text editor field isn't recommended.

Comment: Since I cannot yet comment on your question: can you give us a little bit more detail about Sitecore version, browser and intended application. The issue reminded me of the one I described above, but of course it still is an assumption based on the information you gave us.

Comment: It's Sitecore 7.5. I've tested it on the latest versions of FF, Chrome and IE and it happens on all of them. I also tested it in the out--of-box Launch Sitecore MVC sample site and it happens there.
Our site is built exactly as you suggest, small bits of content as page building blocks. It doesn't matter how large the text box is, if it's far down on the page, when the page scrolls back to the top, you loose your spot on the page. You have to scroll back down after editing and figure out where you were. Here's a video of it:
http://screencast.com/t/e44nMCRx

Comment: Thank you for this additional comment: I now understand what you mean. Because you wrote "behavior for the rich text editor dialog" I thought you meant a scrolling issue _within_ the rich text editor dialog and thus assuming you had a lot of content in one rich text field.. I will look for an answer to your question, but I do not have it right away, since this appears to be different then what I initially thought it was.

Comment: Any news on that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the positioning of the jqueryModalDialogsFrame from absolut to fixed:

`#jqueryModalDialogsFrame{
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0px !important;
    left:0px !important;
}`